# Shaka-player videos not playing in MacOS Safari, working fine in Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Working code is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlYTc.png)I have a non-drm video that is playing as expected in chrome but doesn't work in Safari. I have added the code snippet for the same.

I tried changing the urls but the issue still persists. Videos are playing fine on chrome but not on safari.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.